# C# Verify Sign Data with Bouncy Castle

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography, digital-signature, bouncycastle

I am trying to sign and verify the singed data in C# using Bouncy Castle. I went through almost everything I found on google but it does not seem to solve my problem. Please have a look at my approach.

```
public class Crypto2
{
    private static RsaKeyParameters MakeKey(String modulusHexString, String exponentHexString, bool isPrivateKey)
    {
        var modulus = new Org.BouncyCastle.Math.BigInteger(modulusHexString);
        var exponent = new Org.BouncyCastle.Math.BigInteger(exponentHexString);

        return new RsaKeyParameters(isPrivateKey, modulus, exponent);
    }

    public static string Sign(string data, string privateModulusHexString, string privateExponentHexString)
    {
        /* Make the key */
        RsaKeyParameters key = MakeKey(privateModulusHexString, privateExponentHexString, true);

        /* Init alg */
        ISigner sig = SignerUtilities.GetSigner("SHA1withRSA");

        /* Populate key */
        sig.Init(true, key);

        /* Get the bytes to be signed from the string */
        var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);

        /* Calc the signature */
        sig.BlockUpdate(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        byte[] signature = sig.GenerateSignature();

        /* Base 64 encode the sig so its 8-bit clean */
        var signedString = Convert.ToBase64String(signature);

        return signedString;
    }

    public static bool Verify(string data, string expectedSignature, string publicModulusHexString, string publicExponentHexString)
    {
        /* Make the key */
        RsaKeyParameters key = MakeKey(publicModulusHexString, publicExponentHexString, false);

        /* Init alg */
        ISigner signer = SignerUtilities.GetSigner("SHA1withRSA");

        /* Populate key */
        signer.Init(false, key);

        /* Get the signature into bytes */
        var expectedSig = Convert.FromBase64String(expectedSignature);

        /* Get the bytes to be signed from the string */
        var msgBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);

        /* Calculate the signature and see if it matches */
        signer.BlockUpdate(msgBytes, 0, msgBytes.Length);
        return signer.VerifySignature(expectedSig);
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string data = "Hello World";

        string privateKeyPath = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/e-MOne-i.key");
        string publicKeyPath = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/m1pay-fpx.cer");

        var key = readPrivateKey(privateKeyPath);

        var publicKey = ReadCertificate(publicKeyPath);

        var SignedData = Crypto2.Sign(data, ((RsaKeyParameters)key.Private).Modulus.ToString(), ((RsaKeyParameters)key.Private).Exponent.ToString());

        bool result = Crypto2.Verify(data, SignedData, ((RsaKeyParameters)publicKey.GetPublicKey()).Modulus.ToString(), ((RsaKeyParameters)publicKey.GetPublicKey()).Exponent.ToString());
    }

    static AsymmetricCipherKeyPair readPrivateKey(string privateKeyFileName)
    {
        AsymmetricCipherKeyPair keyPair;

        using (var reader = File.OpenText(privateKeyFileName))
            keyPair = (AsymmetricCipherKeyPair)new PemReader(reader).ReadObject();

        return keyPair;
    }

    static X509Certificate ReadCertificate(string filename)
    {
        X509CertificateParser certParser = new X509CertificateParser();

        Stream stream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open);
        X509Certificate cert = certParser.ReadCertificate(stream);
        stream.Close();

        return cert;
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Does the verify-process fail (i.e. returns the `Verify`-method `false`)? Is an exception thrown? Anyway, I can't reproduce a problem (using my own private key and certificate), especially the verify-process is successful. Maybe there is a problem with your key pair, i.e. private and public keys / certificate don't match, or the certificate has expired or something like that?

Comment: Public and public key provided by another team. Can't say for sure if there's any problem with the key. The problem is Verify method returns false.

Comment: Since the code runs fine on my system, it's probably the key. You can create your _own_ private key and certificate for testing purposes, e.g. [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-certificate-self). If the code then also runs on your system, it would strengthen this assumption and you would have to contact the other team for a valid key.

Comment: Topaco, thank u very much. It's now working. I figured out the problem.

Comment: Please post your answer, if you don't mind, so others can also see what the issue was.